# Properly instantiating a template instance so that everything is present (model data, filters, event handlers)

Tags: polymer

I'm a bit of trouble instantiating a custom template, and making all the bindings work. My custom element which has to do this is quite similar to polymer/core-list, with a few differences. Like core-list, the parent adds the element invokes my custom element, and adds a template as its content, as [seen here](https://github.com/urandom/readeef/blob/3edb954a60b30b7eb1fdf7d7cf75e8d1d39266fc/templates/components/rf-content-list.tmpl#L41).

Unlike core-list, the element adds an id to this template, and creates a few templates which refer to that one, as [seen here](https://github.com/urandom/readeef/blob/3edb954a60b30b7eb1fdf7d7cf75e8d1d39266fc/static/js/rf-article-display.js#L33). Finally, when the time comes, these new templates are used to [create a few elements](https://github.com/urandom/readeef/blob/3edb954a60b30b7eb1fdf7d7cf75e8d1d39266fc/static/js/rf-article-display.js#L136) and add them in the dom.

That's all fine and good, and mostly, it works correctly. The model data is used to fill the resulting element correctly, and the default filters work, thanks to the PolymerExpressions used as a bindingDelegate. However, [event handlers](https://github.com/urandom/readeef/blob/3edb954a60b30b7eb1fdf7d7cf75e8d1d39266fc/templates/components/rf-content-list.tmpl#L46) do not seem to work.

I don't know whether the handler function can't be found in whatever scope is used, or something else is at play here. The only thing I currently know is that the on-tap attribute value is empty when I look at the polymer-icon-button through the web inspector. [With a very similar usage](https://github.com/urandom/readeef/blob/3edb954a60b30b7eb1fdf7d7cf75e8d1d39266fc/templates/components/rf-content-list.tmpl#L26) using the core-list, the event handler works. The web inspector there shows the polymer expression as the value of the on-tap attribute. And [both](https://github.com/urandom/readeef/blob/3edb954a60b30b7eb1fdf7d7cf75e8d1d39266fc/static/js/rf-content-list.js#L165) [handlers](https://github.com/urandom/readeef/blob/3edb954a60b30b7eb1fdf7d7cf75e8d1d39266fc/static/js/rf-content-list.js#L143) are defined in the parent element which contains the invokations of core-list and my element, and the templates which are passed to the corresponding contents.

Comment: Have you tried setting up the event listener manually?

Comment: No reason to try it, it will work. I want to make the declaration work, not do workarounds.